# Show 3 letters in ps language switcher prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, iso

is it possibile in prestashop 1.7.6 to show 3 characters in language switcher?
To show 2 caracters iso code I used {$current_language.iso_code} and it works.
I nead to show 3 char (eg,: ENG instead of EN).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it directly in the template file,
you can use the language name, truncate it to 3 characters and capitalize it:

`{$current_language.name|upper|truncate:3:'':true}`